# How to calculate length of each Huffman code?

Tags: python, huffman-code

The output for the code looks like this how can I calculate the length of the code lets say here I got Huffman lengths 1,10,11 now how can I calculate the length of each code so that I get `{1,2,2}`.
I tried to print some things but it was printing just the last one (11).

```
 Char | Huffman code 
----------------------
 'P_0' |           1
 'P_1' |          10
 'P_2' |          11
```

The code was in this link https://www.section.io/engineering-education/huffman-coding-python/

Comment: Could you provide the code that just prints the last one? If I understand what you want correctly, you just wrap your `huffman_code[id]` in the second last line into a `len()` call.

Comment: yes.`print(huffman_code[id])`

Comment: `print(len(huffman_code[id]))` but keep it in the for loop.

Comment: When I do that it is just giving me the length of the last one. I would like to store those lengths in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Adding at the bottom of the file :

```py
lengths = tuple(len(huffman_code[id]) for id in range(len(freq)))
print(lengths)
```

output :

```
Enter the string to compute Huffman Code: bar
 Char | Huffman code 
----------------------
 'b'  |           1
 'a'  |          00
 'r'  |          01
Average length of the code: 1.650000
(1, 2, 2)
```

I get `(1, 2, 2)`.